# Using ArcGIS Polygon to Raster tool does not divide resulting raster on cells?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, polygon

I try to create raster composed of small (5x5 m) cells (pixels) from a polygon in ArcGIS-10.
I created a polygon (as a single object), and use Feature to Raster Tool and Polygon to Raster tool (of Conversions tools). I assigned "output cell size" as 5 m. 
In both tools the program creates raster but without cells, so as a single object. The attribute table of the final raster has 1 line with Value = 1 and  Count = 61394.

So, as I understand, it has 61394 cells with value = 1, but for some reason the program does not divide it into the cells themselves.

My first polygon and the data frame have UTM Coordinate system, so all data - in metres.

What I have to do for create this raster correctly?

My ultimate goal -  to cut my first big polygon (that was created as a single object) by grid of equal small cells 5x5 m. I went toward the creation  raster at first, because I didn’t find a direct way.

Comment: @Vince I think that you are spot on. Could you write your comment as an answer ?

Comment: Many thanks, Vince, it works! My question is closed.

Comment: The best way to thank @vince is to upvote his answer and click the green accept button next to it.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't sound like an application for the raster datatype.  I think what you really want is to use [Create Fishnet (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) to generate a vector which will overlay the other data.

I would caution you about the use of such a tiny fishnet size.  Unless your data is of submillimeter precision over a small area (as in an archeology dig), five meters is probably going to result in a great many *very* small features, which are likely to perform very poorly.